# How to enable vertical scroll bar for legends in highcharts implemented in angular 8

Tags: highcharts, angular8

Is there a way to get vertical scrollbar for legends in highcharts implemented in angular.

Version: "highcharts": "^7.2.0"

legend options defined as below -

```
legend: {
        align: "right",
        enabled: true,
        layout: "vertical",
        maxHeight: 500,
        margin: 10,
        useHTML: true,
        verticalAlign:'top',
        x: 0,
        y: 100,
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'grey',
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          textOverflow: null,
          textShadow: 'none',
          fontFamily: 'BT_Font_Regular'
        }
      }
```

Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend

There is no option to enable vertical scroll for legends in panel here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
more details or clarify of problem, include [example] of your code, include error message, include the current result, include the expected result,
 provide more information about the problem: 
used tools, screenshots
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If the number of items in the legend requires more space to render than it is defined in the `legend.maxHeight` the navigation shows up - that's the default behavior.
Here is a demo that shows how to control the navigation by scrolling:

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s4zpLc1b/

In case of rendering the regular vertical scroll bar please analyze this topic: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/1256991-scrolling-legends